# Examples of sites that use JQuery UI

Tags: html, jquery-ui, web

As the title of the question states, are there any examples of sites that make extensive use of JQuery UI?

This would include either the widgets or CSS framework.

(Google does not readily produce an answer as it's difficult to filter out those sites the just use JQuery by itself.)

**EDIT**

A few answers have suggested the ["Sites Using JQuery UI"](http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery_UI) page, but this was very out of date and now seems to have been removed completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course the first website that comes into mind on this subject is http://jqueryui.com/demos/ (nothing better for examples, code and documentation)

you can also try to visit http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates (they have a lot of themes created with jquery and jquery-ui, and you can view all the demos for free)

http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery_UI might give you more answers, but i don't know how recently is has been updated

Answer (score 1):

Check this out -> http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery_UI

Here you find a list of jquery ui pages! It was the **second** link in google search!

Comment: I have seen that site. Unfortunately it seems to be extremely out of date with many of the sites listed apparently no longer using JQuery UI (although many still use JQuery itself).

Comment: Than you should say this in your question. In **every** answer you can read the same link.

Comment: Edited to indicate that page doesn't really have much useful information any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link: http://www.republicof3.com/50-amazing-examples-of-jquery-based-websites/

Those Sites are using jQuery, not sure if all of them use jQuery UI.

It was Posted By Labib Jaffar on April 10, 2012.